# Is there a way to spawn Unicorn processes and have them load fully before they are accessed to process requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, unicorn

I am running Unicorn on Heroku. I notice when we scale web dynos up. These new web dynos are being accessed right after it is spawned. In the logs we are getting:

```
Request timeout" error with 30 seconds limit (i.e. service=30000ms)
```

As soon as a dyno starts, traffic will be sent to it. If Unicorn is still spinning up child processes as these requests arrive, then they will likely time out, especially if your app takes a while to boot.

Is there a way to spawn Unicorn child processes without them being accessed by requests, until the app is fully loaded?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually something else and something I've encountered before.

Essentially, when you scale you're seeing your dyno get created and your slug being deployed onto it.  At this point your slug is initialised.  The routing mesh will start sending requests through the moment this has happened, as it sees the dyno as up and ready to rock.

However, (and this is where I found the problem), it takes time for your application to spin up to respond to the request (Unicorn is up, Rails is still initialising) and you get the 30 second timeout.

The only way I could fix this was to get my app starting up in less than 30 seconds repeatedly which I finally achieved by updating to a current version of Rails.  I've also found some increases by also updating to [try running on Ruby 1.9.3](http://railsapps.github.com/rails-heroku-tutorial.html)

Comment: Hi, I am currently running on Rails 3.1.3. Are you suggesting 3.2x? Unfortunately, the Heroku Cedar stack does not support Ruby 1.9.2 yet. Last time I checked

Comment: It most definitely does support 1.9.2.  1.9.3 support is currently beta, but I'm finding it absolutely fine.

Comment: Ooop, typo. Meant to say. Cedar Stack does not support 1.9.3. But yea, it is on Experimental mode. Were you suggesting the difference is with Rail 3.2.x or 3.1.x?

Comment: What about the configuration for `preload_app` as described at http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html and https://github.com/blog/517-unicorn Have you tried something similar?